# Autofilling cookies in fetch (like a browser)

Tags: node.js, cookies, get, request, fetch

I have a fetch request that is getting blocked because I do not have cookies enabled. The error looks on the outside like this:

[image: Error 1020]

But I looked at the HTML and it says I need to enable cookies. I looked at various node packages like [fetch-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-cookie), but when I tried to use it, it didn't polyfill the cookies (send the cookies automatically).

Is there a way to automatically send cookies like it's a browser? I know of puppeteer and phantomjs, but I do not want to use these alternatives, I would prefer to use fetch or a type of request.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [reverse proxy](https://medium.com/intrinsic/why-should-i-use-a-reverse-proxy-if-node-js-is-production-ready-5a079408b2ca) like [cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) to modify the headers.